# How to show comments under a post like facebook does?

Tags: php, mysql, entity-relationship

I'm trying to make a facebook wall-alike php script.

It loads the posts stuff, photo url and user stuff like username and user id from my MySQL database. It also checks if the post is just a comment to another post (parentof). I can present all the original posts with pictures with a simple do-while using  tags .

But how could I present the comments under every post? I guess with another do-loop, but how?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

require_once "config.php";
    $result = mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
    $result = mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
    $wallhaku = mysql_query("SELECT `wall`.`post_id`, `wall`.`parentof`, `wall`.`sentby`, `wall`.`text`, `wall`.`image_url`, `users`.`username`, `users`.`photopath`, `users`.`name`, `users`.`member_id` FROM `wall` LEFT JOIN `users` ON `wall`.`sentby` = `users`.`member_id` WHERE parentof=0 ORDER BY post_id DESC") or die (mysql_error());
    $row_wallhaku = mysql_fetch_array($wallhaku);


<table width="800" height="120" border="0" cellpadding="10">
<?php $i=0; $numberpage=1;
    do {
    $wallid = $row_wallhaku['post_id'];
    $parenthaku = mysql_query("SELECT post_id, parentof FROM wall WHERE parentof=$wallid") or die (mysql_error());
    $row_parenthaku = mysql_num_rows($parenthaku);

      <td width="120" align="left">
      <img src=<?php echo $row_wallhaku['photopath']; ?> height=    "100" width="100">
      </td>
      <td width="600" align="left">
    <a href="member.php?id=<?php echo $row_wallhaku['member_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_wallhaku['name']?></a><br /><p><?php echo $row_wallhaku['text'];
    if($row_wallhaku['image_url']=="0") {

    <p align="right"><?php echo $row_parenthaku ?> kommenttia.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $row_wallhaku['post_id']; ?>">Lue, kommentoi</a> <?php } ?></td>
<?php $i++; if($i%$numberpage==0) echo "</tr>";
if($row_wallhaku['image_url']!="0")
    {

    <tr>
    <td width='800' colspan='2' align='center'>
    <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $row_wallhaku['post_id']; ?>"><img src=<?php echo $row_wallhaku['image_url']; ?> height="180"></a>
    <p align="right"><?php echo $row_parenthaku ?> kommenttia.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $row_wallhaku['post_id']; ?>">Lue, kommentoi</a>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Placed the code there for you. To insert code, you can indent 4 spaces, or use the {} icon on the editor, or use backticks (` or alt+096). Not a solution, but have you tried with [disqus](http://disqus.com) ? It's the same used on the jquery api site, to give a practical example; that would save you a lot of work!

Comment: So the code just checks the posts row by row and check if it has a picture attached. If it foes, it will post a picture under the post.

Comment: Yeah and thanks for placing it here!

Comment: I don't want to use any ready-to-use software :P I want to make it by myself. May sound like crazy but I just want to. And I have gotten this far so... why abandon now?!

Answer (score 0):

In case that the relation between posts is one to many , You need to use 2 queries.
The first query will get the data of the topic (the post).
The other query will get the data of all the comments which "parentof" equals the topic's id.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$getTopic = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id='$id'");
$topic = mysql_fetch_array($getTopic);

$getComments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE parentOf='{$topic['id']}'");
while($comment = mysql_fetch_array($getComments))
{
 echo $comment['title']; //You should use a "view" functin which handles the HTML and staff.
}
```